# Mysql select only child from a table tree

Tags: mysql, parent-child

I have a table name `tbl_section` this table is like that

```
db_secid   db_secname   db_secdesc    db_parent
1          Electrical                 NULL
2          Mechanical                 NULL
3          Plumbing                   NULL
4          Cables                      1
5          Lamps                       1
6          HDMI                        4
```

I want to select only the children of a row with `db_parent=NULL`. From the table above the result will be only `Cables` and `Lamps`.

I try with this query

```
select 
s1.db_secname 
from tbl_section as s1
LEFT JOIN tbl_section as s2
ON 
s1.db_secid=s2.db_parent
WHERE s2.db_parent IS NULL
```

But this query give me a result I don't want this the result I have from this query

```
Mechanical,Plumbing,Lamps,HDMI
```

How can i solve this problem and have only the children who have a parent with `db_parent = NULL`?

Comment: Why do jo do a `LEFT JOIN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply **perform a `JOIN`**, this will already **filter out rows that have no parent**. Furthermore you also **swapped you parent-child relation**: it should be `s1.db_parent = s2.db_secid`, not `s1.db_secid=s2.db_parent`:

```
SELECT s1.db_secname
FROM tbl_section AS s1
     JOIN tbl_section AS s2 ON s1.db_parent = s2.db_secid
WHERE s2.db_parent IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use inner join

```
select t1.db_secname
from tbl_section as t1
inner join tbl_section as t2 
      on t2.db_parent is null and t2.db_secid = t1.db_parent
```